# punctuation removal without removing emojis

Tags: python

How would I remove just the punctuation without removing the emoji.
I assume there maybe a way to do this with regex? but unsure.

```
sentence = ['hello', 'world', '!', '']

def remove_punct(token):
    return [word for word in token if word.isalpha()]

print(remove_punct(sentence))
#output
#['hello', 'world']
#desired output
#['hello', 'world', '']
```

Comment: what if sentence contains ``"..."``? (three dots) Or ``"?!"``?

Answer (score 8):

One approach:

```
from string import punctuation

sentence = ["hello", "world", "!", ""]

punct_set = set(punctuation)


def remove_punct(token):
    return [word for word in token if word not in punct_set]


print(remove_punct(sentence))
```

**Output**

```
['hello', 'world', '']
```

The variable `punctuation` includes:

```
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

If there is a word composed of multiple punctuation symbols, you can use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint), to filter out those words that contains at least one punctuation:

```
# notice the ...
sentence = ["hello", "world", "!", "", "..."]

def remove_punct(token):
    return [word for word in token if punct_set.isdisjoint(word)]

print(remove_punct(sentence))
```

**Output** *(using set.isdisjoint)*

```
['hello', 'world', '']
```

Finally if you want to keep words that contain at least one non-punctuation symbol use [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) as below:

```
# notice the ... and Mr.
sentence = ["hello", "world", "mr.", "!", "", "..."]

def remove_punct(token):
    return [word for word in token if not punct_set.issuperset(word)]

print(remove_punct(sentence))
```

**Output** *(set.issuperset)*

```
['hello', 'world', 'mr.', '']  # mr. is kept because it contains mr
```

Comment: You don't need the line `punct_set = set(punctuation)`. You can just use `return [word for word in token if word not in punctuation]`

Comment: I know, but punctuation is a string and punct_set is a set, in general using sets is faster but I do agree that the string is not that long so perhaps there is no advantage. need to benchmark it

Comment: Creating a set from the string requires iterating through the string's characters, anyway, right? It might be worth it if you intend to do this operation for lots of strings, though, because the set would only need to be created once.

Answer (score 1):

Using Unicode code points:
ASCII characters characters in Unicode are all below 127, or 255 if you take into account extended ASCII.

```py
sentence = ['hello', 'world', '!', '']
result = [word for word in sentence if (word.isalpha() or ord(word[0]) > 127)]
# ord('') = 129324
# use index to prevent multicharacter words breaking the code
print(result)
# ['hello', 'world', '']
```

The ord() function in python returns the (usually) Unicode code point of a character. Common punctuations are in ASCII and thus have a code point of less than 127.

Note that due to this, if the python program is not run in a Unicode (or similar) environment, this code could likely break (others utilizing a extensive list of punctuation like the string.punctuation in another answer may also break, but it should be easier to fix that, by adding more punctuations (like nbsp) than fixing this). However, if it is not run in Unicode environment, the display of the emoji should be more important to worry about.